# Laravel insert and update to JSON not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can't figure out why JSON field is being ignored.

This one doesn't work:

```
Registries::create([
    'nr' => $old_document->no,
    'metas->name' => 'r01',
]);
```

In model I have set:

```
protected $casts = [
        'metas' => 'array',
    ];
```

And:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'nr',
        'metas'
    ];
```

I think the problem is in attributes casting, because this one is working:

```
Registries::create([
    'nr' => $old_document->no,
    'metas' => json_encode(['name'=>'r01']),
]);
```

I'm not getting any errors just JSON column stays empty.

Comment: `'metas->name'` is wrong. Remove quotes.

Comment: No, how come you can remove it this will be syntax error in PHP.

Comment: Sure you can. Array key is just string and you can always use variable that returns string for an array key. As same as `$array[$index]`. Post table structure, it will be very helpful to us.

Answer (score 0):

So it seams that `$metas->name` is working only for updating, in my case I need to insert like this:

```
Registries::create([
    'nr' => $old_document->no,
    'metas' => ['name'=>'r01']
]);
```

Comment: Are You sure that You can push array data to string field in mysql table?

Comment: It’s Laravel attribute casting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fan of attribute casting in relational dabatases.

So it's just my guess based on documentation about `array`.

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON.

You're trying to put associative array which for JSON is an object.

I might guess that it's a bug.

So try to typecast it on insert:

```
Registries::create([
    'nr' => $old_document->no,
    'metas' => (object)['name'=>'r01'],
]);
```

**attribute casting**

and make it object:

```
protected $casts = [
    'metas' => 'object',
];
```

Comment: I posted my answer already, and in my question you can see that I’m using attribute casting so Laravel will do encoding and decoding automatically. And it’s not simple string field it’s JSON field.

Comment: @RomkaLTU oh, now I see. try to make it an object